# How to Programmatically Explore a JSON with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to write a javascript/jquery piece of code to display a **general JSON** into an html view. Basically, I get an unknown json, I parse it, and I have to build html elements reflecting the the JSON structure. Of course it is my choice to associate an html element to a peculiar JSON structure.
For example, if I get the following:

```
[
    {
        "audi": {
            "type": "a4",
            "year": "1999",
            "color": "red",
            "price": "3500"
        }
    },
    {
        "fiat": {
            "type": "idea",
            "year": "2009",
            "color": "silver",
            "price": "4500"
        }
    }
]
```

I'd like to have a div containing two divs containing 4 spans each, with the type, year, color and price of the car.
How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:**

If you want to follow an approach decoupled form any peculiar implementation you'll have to follow the suggestion of the chosen answer, however it is worth to mention [this plugin (json2html)](http://json2html.com/) which seems to be **very promising**.

Comment: What have you found in researching this problem and what have you tried?

Comment: Downvote - no research effort

Comment: Your question doesn't describe clearly if you found out how to [parse JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) already. If you have found that out, then the question is more about displaying an unknown object structure than about parsing JSON.

Comment: Try using `eval('(' + result + ')');` where `result` contains your json.

Comment: let me clarify. I'm not a javscript guy, so I understand I'm missing some basic concepts. Clearly I looked for javascrit JSON library but as far as I've searched it seems that it supports mainly serialization issues, I mean, how to turn a json into an object. Well my problem is that I don't know the json structure and so I won't know the object. I need some GENERAL method which allow me to traverse general json (or object if you prefer). In other words I think I need some getChildren(), getParent() methods

Comment: Here's a fiddle doing pretty-printing of a json using jQuery (for parsing json) and basic javascript for rendering as html (plus css for styling) : http://jsfiddle.net/CFpX3/

Answer (score 0):

You can jQuery's json parser `jQuery.parseJSON` [jQueryDocumentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: so I will have an object. But now I need to explore the object, and I don't know how to do this. In other words, taking the exmple posted in the question, to get the audi type, I'd write `var type = audi.type;`. It works, but I don't now that exist a `type` attribute. It would be quite better if I could access the obj properties in a general way like the following `myJson[i].getChildren()`

Comment: Here yoy have some examples: http://jsfiddle.net/cKFMn/7/

Comment: @Wood : Very nice bud.

Comment: @Wood thank you: it is exactly what I was looking for! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it!